# Trying to add a count to distinct statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns:

A column that will contain data.

So Column 1 has number of records. These records in column 1 i have to narrow it down to a distinct. I then want to know how many of the records in column 2 contain the data from coulmn 1.

So let's say:

```
Column 1 - AABB 
Column 2 - 111, 112.
```

How many of these in column 2 contain AABB just as a example and a count possibly on column 2. I also need to distinct column 1.

EDIT:  (originally in an answer)

Sorry my question was phrased a bit silly.

So I want distinct column 1.

Then in column 2, i want to know the amount of records that are in column 2 contained under each distinct record stated in column 1. So that be a count.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, I think you need this:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: Sorry my question was phrased a bit silly.

So I want distinct column 1.

Then in column 2, i want to know the amount of records that are in column 2 contained under each distinct record stated in column 1. So that be a count.

Comment: @user3588635 Then the provided query is exactly what you need. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah that works great, i just want to verify at the end with a total count. Like just to make sure it all matches the figure i was hoping for.

Comment: Way it looks now is column 1 has aa and column 2 has the count figure ie 50. I got this for 100 records. I just want to add them all together now to give a final total.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it, assuming your table is like this and the data is like below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DataTbl (
Product VARCHAR(100),
Qty SMALLINT
);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.DataTbl
VALUES ('Chocolate bars', 3),
   ('Chocolate bars', 5),
   ('Milk', 2),
   ('Milk', 4),
   ('Crisps', 6),
   ('Fizzy Drinks', 10);

---Your desired query
SELECT DISTINCT (Product) AS 'Product', SUM(Qty) AS 'TotalQty'
         FROM dbo.DataTbl
          GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: Way it looks now is column 1 has aa and column 2 has the count figure ie 50. I got this for 100 records. I just want to add them all together now to give a final total.

Comment: Can you please provide an example code of what you have? substitute your real columns/data, in case you can't list your actual columns/data for sample ones but provide similar values please so I can assist.